# How to get LDA projection matrix in matlab fitcdiscr

Tags: matlab, matrix

I didn't find anything about projection matrix in [fitcdiscr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcdiscr.html) help page. Is it possible to extract projection matrix from a model?

If not, do you know some matlab LDA implementation that outputs this matrix. I really need only eigenvectors/projection matrix from LDA.

Comment: LDA = Linear discriminant analysis